# Example of integral domain with infinitely ascending chain of ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples

> I am looking for an integral domain in which we have an infinitely ascending chain of ideals.

Clearly, this can't be a PID. Also, I am looking for examples other than infinite dimensional fields, integral domains like $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$.